# How do I bypass or remove the iCloud activation lock on iPad2?

Tags: itunes, ipad

I found an iPad at my working office which was owned by the former director. Unfortunately, he locked it with his Apple ID. I restored the iPad via iTunes because I thought it would wipe everything out alongside with the Apple ID on it but it was not working at all. After restoration , the iPad asks me for language, country and Wi-Fi. Then it asks me for the Apple ID of former director. I can't find or contact that person. Plus, I don't have any information about that ID. I want to unlock that iPad for office purposes. How do I unlock it? The model is iPad2, A1395.

I found IMEIUnlock sites but it asks me for 39.99$. Is it really reliable?

P.S - Trust me, I'm not a thief.

Comment: It's really simple: *You don't.*

Comment: Apparently you can contact him by his email... iCloud email by the way, so you can contact him by FaceTime, iMessage, email...